# Can we do something like mapName[key]++ in javascript like we can do in C++

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I'm new at JS. When I work on frequency maps in C++, I can do something like:

```
map<char,int> newMap = {{'a',1}, {'b',2}, {'c',3}, {'d',4}};
newMap['a']++;
```

And this increases the value corresponding to 'a' to 2 from 1
But I can't do:

```
let m = new Map()
m.set('a',1)
m.get('a')++
```

Can anybody tell me a workaround for this?
Thanks

Comment: Use an object (`{ }`) instead of a `Map`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Map, there is no way to change primitive values in a Map other than calling `map.set` each time. But if you were using a plain object instead, you could use shorthand syntax very similar to what you're familiar with in C++.

```js
const m = { a: 1 };
m.a++;
console.log(m);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. But would using object be a good choice for mapping frequency of english characters, for which I usually create a map or 256 sized array in C++? @certainperformance

Comment: Sure, an object would be fine for that. Maps can be better when using dynamic keys (or `Object.create(null)`, but for pre-defined characters, ordinary objects that inherit from `Object.prototype` are fine.